# Dual Screen screen adjustments for wallpaper

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a dual screen setup one is horizontal one is vertical, problem is that the wallpaper on the vertical one displays as horizontal so i have black space above and below the wallpaper.

How can turn the wallpaper around so it displays correctly on the vertical screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article on howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/dual-monitors-use-a-different-wallpaper-on-each-desktop-in-vista-or-xp/) describes an application that can do that.

It basically automates the steps in Anders' answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you make your own wallpaper by editing a picture or image file. If you have a resolution of 1280x1024 on your monitors. Then make a file that has the dimensions 2304x1280 if you have the horizontal on the left and the vertical to the right. (Should work either way though...)

Within that picture you create regions that match your screen sizes and orientations. When you set your wallpaper make sure that it is set as tiled to get the desired effect.

Comment: i have the horizontal to the left and vertical to the right, now will the same work

Comment: Realize that I made a typo there... Cannot see why it shouldn't work either way. I actually tried with a setup like yours.

Comment: sweet ill check it out then